# Angular Unit Test case - How can we write unit test case for Subscribe and response

Tags: angular, unit-testing

below is my method and I'm new in writing unit test case in angular.

```
fetchControlDetailById(controlName) {
   this.controlService.fetchControlDetailById(controlName).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
         this.controlDetails = res;
         this.portiqueArr = res.portiqueList;
         this.controlTest = res.controlTest;
         this.controlPresentBool = res.controlPresent;
         this.testSource = res.controlHistoryDto;

         // show and hide dropdown section
         this.showPortiqueEssaiBool = true;
         if (res.controlPresent) {
            this.showPortiqueEssaiBool = false;
         }
      },  
    });
}
```

[image]

After running the test case - it is showing below part is not covered - pls check below image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 it('should fetch control details by ID and update component properties', () => {
const controlName = 'my-control-id';
const mockResponse = {
  portiqueList: [/*...*/],
  controlTest: {/*...*/},
  controlPresent: true,
  controlHistoryDto: [/*...*/]
};

spy = spyOn(controlService, 'fetchControlDetailById').and.returnValue(of(mockResponse));

component.fetchControlDetailById(controlName);

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(controlName);

expect(component.controlDetails).toEqual(mockResponse);
expect(component.portiqueArr).toEqual(mockResponse.portiqueList);
expect(component.controlTest).toEqual(mockResponse.controlTest);
expect(component.controlPresentBool).toBe(mockResponse.controlPresent);
expect(component.testSource).toEqual(mockResponse.controlHistoryDto);

expect(component.showPortiqueEssaiBool).toBe(true);
if (mockResponse.controlPresent) {
  expect(component.showPortiqueEssaiBool).toBe(false);
}
```

});

Comment: Thank you so much Yogita for help ! @yogita